# convert python dict like string to java hashmap

Tags: java, python, text-parsing

I am working on a project which has a python wrapper around java code.
So, there is a communication between python and java code. (I am aware of jython, but we wanted to keep each implementation separate.)

To talk from python to java, we pass a string like

```
{
    "1-1": {
        "Max Capacity (MB)": "393216",
        "Current Capacity (MB)": "24576",
        "Max Devices": "12",
        "Populated": "12"
    },
    "1-3": {
        "Max Capacity (MB)": "262144",
        "Current Capacity (MB)": "8192",
        "Max Devices": "32",
        "Populated": "2"
    },
    "1-2": {
        "Max Capacity (MB)": "393216",
        "Current Capacity (MB)": "4096",
        "Max Devices": "12",
        "Populated": "1"
    }
}
```

which is  a dict in python and we pass as a string to java code.

Is there I library in java which does parsing a python dict like string to a java hash-map or equivalent for easy traversal?

**Solution:**

The json solution worked. Used simplejson in python to convert the dict to json format 
and java gson library. Here is the java part:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class ReadFromJson {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Type mapOfStringObjectType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String,String>>>() {}.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Map<String, Map<String,String>> obj = gson.fromJson(jsonStringToBeRead, mapOfStringObjectType);
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should communicate via JSON?

Comment: I tried that but I am doing something like java -dname="TheAboveString"
and retriving it by System.getProperty("name"), so not able to pass a well formed json..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried that but I am doing something like `java -dname="TheAboveString"` and retriving it by System.getProperty("name"), so not able to pass a well formed json.. – kmad 15 mins ago

...and why are you passing it as a system property?

Just pipe in the JSON `echo "TheAboveString" | java` and dump it from stdin to a JSON parser. This should be a little easier and *much* safer using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: its because I need to run a junit test with the "TheAboveString" argument. There was no other way to pass an argument to a single junit test.

Comment: @kmad Well, I suppose you could swap `System.in` with another `InputStream` that sends fake data. Maybe you should refactor your code so that the decoding method takes an `InputStream` as an argument so that it is easy to inject test data. Anyway, I don't think you should avoid JSON because you can't send strings into the application.